# How do I retrieve default validation messages from Hibernate Validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm trying to retrieve a default validation error-message using `MessageSource`. The code I'm working with uses reflection to retrieve the value of the `message` parameter. On a constraint that does not override the `message` parameter, I would like to retrieve the default error message. When I invoke the `message` method on the validation annotation, I get `{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}` (for example, for the `@NotBlank` annotation). I then tried to use `MessageSource` to get the error message like so:

```
String message = messageSource.getMessage(key, null, Locale.US);
```

I tried setting `key` to `{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}`, `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message` (removed braces) and even `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank` but I keep getting `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

A clarification. I am under the impression that Spring comes with a default `message.properties` file for its constraints. Am I correct in this assumption?

**UPDATE**

Changing the name of the question to better reflect what I was trying to do.

Comment: There are certainly auto-generated messages for certain constraint violations, but I din't think it's expressed as a `messages.properties` file.

Comment: @skaffman do you know where spring/hibernate-validator gets these message from?

Comment: 'fraid not, no. I'm pretty sure it's Hibernate Validator that's doing it, though, not Spring.

Comment: @skaffman, I downloaded the source to hibernate validator and it looks like these messages come from a `ValidationMessages.properties` file. I'd assume that this would be in the jar, so I'm not sure why it's not resolving it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running into a [blog post](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2010/06/whats-new-in-hibernate-validator-41.html) from one of the Hibernate guys, and after digging around in the Hibernate Validator source, I think I've figured it out:

```
public String getMessage(final Locale locale, final String key) {
    PlatformResourceBundleLocator bundleLocator = new PlatformResourceBundleLocator("org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages");
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = bundleLocator.getResourceBundle(locale);

    try {
       final String k = key.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
       return resourceBundle.getString(k);
    }
    catch (MissingResourceException e) {
       return key;
    }
}
```

So first, you have to instantiate a `PlatformResourceBundleLocator` with the default validation messages. Then you retrieve a `ResourceBundle` from the locator and use that to get your message. I don't believe this performs any interpolation though. For that you have to use an interpolator; the blog post I linked to above goes into more detail about that.

**UPDATE**

Another (easier) way is to update your `applicationContext.xml` and do this:

```
<bean id="resourceBundleSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now your `MessageSource` is populated with the default messages and you can do `messageSource.getMessage()`. In fact, this is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.4.5

In case someone needs this for testing:

```
package some.package;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;

public class NotNullTest {

  private static MessageSource ms;
  private static String VAL_MSG_NOT_NULL;

  @BeforeAll
  static void setUpClass() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    ms = messageSource;
  }

  @BeforeEach 
  void setUp() {
    VAL_MSG_NOT_NULL = ms.getMessage("javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message", null, Locale.ROOT);
    assertThat(VAL_MSG_NOT_NULL).isNotNull();
    assertThat(VAL_MSG_NOT_NULL).isNotBlank();
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
    assertThat(VAL_MSG_NOT_NULL).isEqualTo("must not be null");
  }
}
```