# How to add custom error messages in Hibernate validator

Tags: hibernate-validator

I have a simple class like this,

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

public class Form implements Serializable {
   @NotNull
   @Length(min = 2, max = 20)
   private String lastName;
}
```

I have messages.properties file in the classpath. It's then loaded via Spring bean as follows,

```
<bean name="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="resourceBundleLocator"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="resourceBundleLocator" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:messages.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

All I want is to get error messages customized according to the bean validated. In other words I want to have each ConstraintViolation object return the error message I have defined in my property file instead of the default one. Is it possible to add message property with a value like this format {xxx.yyyy.zzzz} and refer that message from the messages.properties file ?

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Form>> inputErrors = validator.validate(form);
```

If I want to customize the default message for @NotNull and @Length, how can I do that?

My experience on Hibernate validation is **zero**, Any sample code or **step by step guide**  would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this resource bundle file holding the message values.

I think you have to use the path to the i.e. `@NotNull` annotation
to override the message by hand! 
like `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull=Notnull error happened!` 
or something like that!

Look here for that :

[Hibernate Validator - The error message](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation)

Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah fritz, it's true, but I don't want to override the default messageTemplate path because I have many @NotNull(and of course other annotations) in my Form class. I want to add specific error messages for each property. Is there an easy way **without** implementing custom MessageInterpolator. I found couple of custom message interpolator implementations, but I don't understand any of these. If you can give me the simplest possible solution with a full  source code !!.

Comment: And also I tried overriding message attribute of each validation annotation with a format like this {vvvv.ssss.rrrt.message}, but when I called the getMessage of ConstraintViolation it's printed as it is, not the message of it.

Comment: I see! the only way which comes to my mind is to create a custom validator which holds a message ! like @MyNotNull + the message?!

or you could do something like this

`
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Car car = new Car(null);

Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(car);

assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
assertEquals("may not be null", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
`
and intercept the message in the object!?

Comment: Ok, I may be crazy, and apologize for that.I have to do this anyway, Is there a way to get the messages(key and value pairs) defined in the messages.properties file? If so I can go for the second option you mentioned earlier.

Comment: Yeah !

don't mind thats a tricky task ! 

try that 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372569/how-do-i-retrieve-default-validation-messages-from-hibernate-validator

what framework are you using. 

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    context().getMessage("key", null, Locale.getDefault());

something like that could do the job if you are using i.e. spring!

Comment: Anyway I got it working by extending Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class; imported messages to Properties object and I can now give any sort of message for every single validation annotation type in the entity.