# Spring Hibernate validation messages

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I have a Person model:

```
public class Person {

    @Min(1)
    private Integer id;

    @Length(min = 5, max = 30)
    @NotEmpty(message = "{NotEmpty.person.name}")
    private String name;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "Min.person.age")
    private Integer age;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I have simple `@RestController` where I have to validate the `@RequestBody`:

```
@RestController
public class PeopleController {

    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public List<Person> add(@Valid @RequestBody Person person) {
        people.add(person);
        return people;
    }

}
```

Here is my simple Spring Config:

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
        final LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return validator;
    }
}
```

*messages.properties*:

```
Min.person.age=Person's {0} must be greater than {1}
NotEmpty.person.name=Person's {0} cannot be empty
NotNull.person.name=Person's {0} cannot be null
Length.person.name=Person's {0} length should be between {1} and {2}
```

Also I've defined `@ControllerAdvice`, which simply returns all error messages from bindings:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        return ex.getBindingResult()
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried different variants to access messages, but, unfortunately, I am getting only the default messages.

When I send invalid data,

```
{
    "id": 999, // valid
    "name": "121", // invalid - too short
    "age": -123 // invalid - negative
}
```

the response is:

```
[
    "length must be between 5 and 30",
    "must be greater than or equal to 0"
]
```

But should be:

```
[
    "Person's age must be greater than 0",
    "Person's name length should be between 5 and 30"
]
```

I am using:

- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator: 5.2.4.Final
- Spring Boot: 1.3.5.RELEASE

Where I am wrong?

Comment: see this question, its might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093468/how-to-add-custom-error-messages-in-hibernate-validator

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, have you resolved it, if yes please tell me how to do it.

Comment: @karthi hi. Find the following repository with resolved issue: https://github.com/ITsvetkoFF/Kv-014

Comment: Hi, thanks, will look into it.

Comment: Hi @AndriiAbramov, I used ResourceBundleMessageSource configuration in my spring config file and used Environment interface to read properties file as done by you, but still I'm getting the default message only. Do I need to configure anything else? The thing is, the same configuration is working properly for Spring MVC applications (i.e. using JSP for front end), but it's not working for Spring Rest applications.

Answer (score 0):

Assume 'messages.properties' is located at root of classpath.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    final ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    return source;
}
```